# How to print the output of a remote terminal with/without color code in TCL?

Tags: terminal, tcl

I have this tcl script which prints the output on a remote terminal . But due to color coding implementation in the scripts , it prints the escape sequence on the remote terminal.
I have approximately 200+ commands and want to make the o/p of all the commands in a readable format with/without any color coding and not the escape sequences .

This is the output which i am getting:
[image: This is the output which i am getting]

This is the expected ouput:
[image: This is the expected ouput.]

Comment: In a well-behaving application, you can set the TERM environment variable to `dumb` or `unknown` to prevent the escape sequences from being inserted in the first place.

Comment: How can i set it for a remote terminal . In my case , it is teraterm.

Comment: You should set it on the side that generates the output, not where it is displayed.

Comment: I swapped your images round as otherwise your question is incoherent.

Comment: Setting the `TERM` environment variable for a remote terminal depends on the details of how you are connecting (which you don't tell us!)

Answer (score 0):

The sequences you want to remove all have the form:

```
escape(hex 1b) "[" (sequence of digits and semi-colon) "m"
```

So you could match these sequences with a regular expression and remove them by substituting the empty string, i.e. assuming the original version is in variable `input` and you want to put this in variable `output` minus the escape sequences:

```
regsub -all -- {\x1b\[[\d;]*m} $input {} output
```

For more info see the manual page at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.html

Comment: Thanks Colin for the response. But what i am looking for is before printing the o/p on the remote terminal ,i want all the escape sequence to be removed and the make the o/p in a readable format.

Comment: In that case you need to search through the original scripts for these escape sequences and edit them out.